# how to clear the query string in PHP

Tags: php

How to Clear the Query string.

my query string is "index.php?name=sugumar&id=49"

using meta tag I redirect the same page. that time the query string values are not cleared.
for that I have used.

> Request.QueryString[1] = string.Empty;

but it shows the error.

> syntax error, unexpected '[' in
>   /home/sugumar

Then I used

> Request.QueryString.Clear();

it shows the error

> Call to undefined function Clear() in
>   /home/sugumar

how to solve this problem? I want to clear the query string values before the meta tag redirect the page.

Comment: This is tagged/titled as PHP, but `Request.QueryString` is ASP. Which are you using?

Comment: I don't see PHP here please clarify your question if possible.

Comment: Are you using a framework that makes PHP look like ASP? If so specify which one it is because this looks like ASP

Comment: You seem to be trying to use ASP syntax in PHP - which explains both errors. You need to use PHP syntax when coding in PHP - they are significantly different from each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
unset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

Other possibility is to simply not specify the query string values when you are redirecting:

```
header('LOCATION: page.php');
```

Or

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
<form action="page.php">
```

If that's how you are doing it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using meta refresh you can not clear the query string.

I would suggest using the header() function in php to redirect instead

```
header("Location: index.php");
```